# Passwords are limited with Regex in Flexi-Auth

Tags: php, regex, codeigniter, security, authentication

### Explanation

In Flexi-Auth, i noticed passwords are limited with the following regex ( only accepts alphanumeric and . , - _ )

```
$config['security']['valid_password_chars'] = '\.\,\-_ a-z0-9';
```

I've read it is bad to limit password characters, so i changed it to the following:

```
$config['security']['valid_password_chars'] = '\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)\+\=\~\<\>\?\:\[\]\{\}\|\.\,\-_ a-z0-9';
```

Now it allows almost all standard special chars except: ' " ` which i didn't allow because i feared might cause issues

### Questions

1. Is my new Regex correct? (i mean i used lots of backslashes)
2. Do you think it might cause any issues that i allowed more characters than the developer settings
3. If there are no issues in doing that, how do i allow everything in there? (no limits) (i tried putting single dot ='.' in there but got an error and didn't work)

### UPDATE

The regex mentioned in comment didn't work, i ended up using this:

```
$config['security']['valid_password_chars'] = '\s\S';
```

This one accepts everything, even though my question is not answered, i just thought i should mention this in case some one gets to this page

Comment: I would say that if the application is hashing or at least encrypting (it likely is doing one of these and it better be), there's no danger in permitting every character.

Comment: I would replace it with `/^.{20,}$/` to enforce a minimum password length of 20 and let people submit whatever characters they want :P

Comment: Yes it is using bcrypt